# No route found for "GET /formulari" in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying to do a simple formulary with Symfony, but I don't know why it doesn't find my route (/formulari).

Here's the function that I have in the src/AppBundle/Controller/PersonsController.php

```
/**
 * Route("/formulari", name="formulari")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // crea una task y le asigna algunos datos ficticios para este ejemplo
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AppBundle::formulari.html.twig', [
        'list' => $form
    ]);
}
```

Here's the formulari.twig.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{{ form(form) }}
```

Here's the error:

> NotFoundHttpException
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route
>   found for "GET /formulari"
>
> at
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:125
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent),
>   'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))   at
>   call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request',
>   object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent),
>   'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))   at
>   call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent),
>   'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   object(GetResponseEvent))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:146)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   object(GetResponseEvent))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
>   1)
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1,
>   true)
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:171)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
>        (web/app_dev.php:29)

Comment: `@Route`. Also, have you got the appropriate `use` statement at the top of the file?

Comment: Wow, that's it! I forgot the @... Thank you!